# Copying a small array into a larger one without changing the target array's size

Tags: java

I want to copy a small array into a larger one. For example:

```
String arr[] = new String[10];
```

Now I have another small array

```
String arr1[] = new String[4];
```

I want to copy `arr1` into `arr` without changing the larger array's length. ie `arr` should maintain a length of 10 and copying of all elements should be successfully.

Can anyone please tell me how can I do this?

Answer (score 42):

Try this:

```
System.arraycopy(arr1, 0, arr, 0, arr1.length);
```

The size of `arr` will not change (that is, `arr.length == 10` will still be `true`), but only the first `arr1.length` elements will be changed. If you want the elements of `arr1` to be copied into `arr` starting somewhere other than the first element, just specify where:

```
System.arraycopy(arr1, 0, arr, offset, arr1.length);
```

If there's a possibility that the offset is so large that the result would run off the end of the destination array, you need to check for that to avoid an exception:

```
System.arraycopy(arr1, 0, arr, offset,
    Math.max(0, Math.min(arr1.length, arr.length - offset - arr1.length)));
```

Comment: +1 because this solution is "dynamic" as the lenght of arrays growns.

Answer (score 6):

To solve this, simply iterate over the small array and add them to the larger array.

```
   for(int i = 0; i < arr1.length(); ++i) {
      arr[i] = arr1[i];
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be a very easy question:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) arr[i] = arr1[i];
```

Comment: the arr size will be shrink till 4. I want size 10.

Comment: No it won't. The leftover items will be unchanged, but the array will be the same length.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the values in `arr` that are beyond the length of `arr1` do:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr1.length(); i++){
    if(i < arr.length()){ // Just in case arr isn't larger
        arr[i] = arr1[i];
    }
}
```

If you want to reset the values in `arr` that are beyond the length of `arr1` do:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++){
    if(i < arr1.length()){ // Just in case arr isn't larger
        arr[i] = arr1[i];
    } else {
        arr[i] = 0; // Or whatever default value you want here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
{
arr[i] = arr1[i];
}
```

will do the job.